# Saving a matrix into an array

Tags: python, readlines

I want to use the data written in a text file with some headers. The file looks like this:

```
#Fruit list
#Prices from different vendors
   Pineapple    4.49   4.29   5.19
   Apple        1.99   1.89   2.19
   Banana       1.99   1.99   1.79
   Kiwi         2.99   2.99   2.99
```

I want to save this table into an array. So far I tried:

```
def fruits():
    items = []
    with open('prices.txt', 'r') as data:
        for line in data.readlines()[2:]:   #Header is always 2 lines 
            items.append(line.strip())
            species = np.array(items)
        return species
```

This returns a 0-D array, while I'm expecting a 2D array. Then I tried removing the append line (which seems unnecessary to begin with) and tried:

```
def fruits():
    items = []
    with open('prices.txt', 'r') as data:
        for line in data.readlines()[2:]:
            species = np.array(line)
        return species
```

But then this returns only the last line. It has to be a really easy fix, but I'm puzzled, especially with the second attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to pandas and numpy then:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

df=pd.read_csv("Filename",index_col=0)
df.to_numpy()
df.to_records() #if index is needed too
```

should give you the required array form of data

**Example:**
Given this file: https://file.io/5mc5MGnh0pZN

I wrote the following to read it:
[image]

And then converted df to numpy array:

[image]

Comment: Yes, totally fine, but when I run this I get: Empty DataFrame

Comment: you might like to specify the field separator: pd.read_csv("Filename",index_col=0,sep='\t'), assuming your file is tab separated

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I also tried the example I gave in the question and that also returned an empty dataframe

Comment: Check the example. Ensure your file has correct delimiter. Sometimes there are multiple spaces instead of tabs. In that case do: pd.read_csv("Filename",index_col=0,header=None, delim_whitespace=True). Specify the name of file that is there at your end.

Comment: It works with '\s+', but converting it to numpy removes the first column (fruit names in the example), which I need to keep. I figured it without pandas, thanks for the help though!

Comment: You may simply do a df.to_records(). I have updated the answer with the same. If this solves the problem more conveniently then do indicate by accepting the answer. Nevertheless do post your own version by which you solved your problem. It will help the community. You may accept your own answer too if that's better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

While @JALO - JusAnotherLivngOrgani's answer works, I'd also like to add an alternative which uses just numpy:

```
    fruits = []
    with open('File.txt') as data:
        for line in data.readlines()[2:]: #Skipping the 2 line header
            fruits.append(line)
        string = [i for item in fruits for i in item.split()] # Gives a 1D list array.
        string = np.array(string).reshape(-1,4) # Converts the list array into 2D numpy array.
```

The file is always 4 columns, but the number of rows vary, so '-1' deals with it.